# Call to undefined relationship on model laravel using scope

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to get 5 posts for each category so I did a little search and ends up here [Getting n Posts per category](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/)
But I'm getting a weird Call to undefined relationship on model when using with scope but it all works fine If I don't use a scope. Here is the **Category Model**

```
   //Relationship with posts
    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
```

**scopeNPerGroup**

```
public function scopeNPerGroup($query, $group, $n = 10)
    {
        // queried table
        $table = ($this->getTable());

        // initialize MySQL variables inline
        $query->from( \DB::raw("(SELECT @rank:=0, @group:=0) as vars, {$table}") );

        // if no columns already selected, let's select *
        if ( ! $query->getQuery()->columns) 
        { 
            $query->select("{$table}.*"); 
        }

        // make sure column aliases are unique
        $groupAlias = 'group_'.md5(time());
        $rankAlias  = 'rank_'.md5(time());

        // apply mysql variables
        $query->addSelect(\DB::raw(
            "@rank := IF(@group = {$group}, @rank+1, 1) as {$rankAlias}, @group := {$group} as {$groupAlias}"
        ));

        // make sure first order clause is the group order
        $query->getQuery()->orders = (array) $query->getQuery()->orders;
        array_unshift($query->getQuery()->orders, ['column' => $group, 'direction' => 'asc']);

        // prepare subquery
        $subQuery = $query->toSql();

        // prepare new main base Query\Builder
        $newBase = $this->newQuery()
            ->from(\DB::raw("({$subQuery}) as {$table}"))
            ->mergeBindings($query->getQuery())
            ->where($rankAlias, '<=', $n)
            ->getQuery();

        // replace underlying builder to get rid of previous clauses
        $query->setQuery($newBase);
    }
```

**Calling Npergroup with relation**

```
public function latestposts()
    {
        return $this->posts()->latest()->nPerGroup('category_id', 5);
    }
```

Post Model Relationship

```
//Post belongs to Category
 public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
```

In my **category controller** I'm calling `latestposts` through

```
$categories = Category::with('latestposts')->get();
```

But I'm getting the error: `Call to undefined relationship on model`

**What I want is:** 
Get the N number of posts per each category but I'm completely lost at this point. Any help would be appreciated

Reference:
[Tweaking Eloquent relations – how to get N related models per parent ?](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/)

Comment: what is the main purpose of your **scope** ?

Comment: Scope is used to get the 5 posts per category @ChiragPatel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am giving this answer based on your purpose that you want 5 posts per category.
So you have Category Model and Post Model.

And in Category Model you have relation with **Post** model like this

```
    //Relationship with posts
    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
```

And in **Post** Model you have relation with **Category** model like this

```
//Post belongs to Category
 public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
```

I show your question you have done SQL queries.

Instead of that, You can use two approaches

1) Give condition while **eagar** loading

```
$categories = Category::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5);
}])->get();
```

> Note: This approach will only work when you take only one result of parent child using **`first()`** method.
>
> To get **n number of posts per category Use this.**

First, you can retrieve all categories with

```
$categories = Category::all();
```

Then you can use foreach loop and in all **$category** you have to give assign new attribute in it like here **latestposts**,

```
foreach ($categories as $category)
{
    $category->latestposts = $category->posts()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(5)->get();
}
```

After this foreach loop you will get latest 5 posts in all categories.

Try this in your code and comment your queries and reviews.

Comment: Yes both are same and I've tried them before digging into research both will give `posts` on only last category

Comment: Yes I have tested this and it's not working. Really sorry for that. Eagar loading will work only for one parent model. So you can use another concept. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Have you tried this currently It is giving me only 5 posts

Comment: Yes.I have tried and it is working.And  you want 5 posts right?

Comment: I want 5 posts for all related categories not just 5 posts. Like If I have categories Tech, Media, Education. Then I want 5 posts of each and every categories of **Tech, Media, Education**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168201/discussion-between-chirag-patel-and-saad-suri).